# Is it possible to have tab autocompletion of remote files for SCP?

Tags: ssh, autocomplete, scp

Given host A / user a and host B / user b, and ssh from A to B: `a@A$ ssh b@B`. Suppose that in B there is a file called `hello.txt`. As we know, if I log into B and look for this file, I can use tab to autocomplete the file name:

```
a@A$ ssh b@B
b@B$ ls h
  hello.txt
```

where at the end of the second line I typed 'tab'.

Now suppose that I am logged into A and I want to copy with scp `hello.txt` from B to A, but I do not remember the full file name, I only remember that the file starts with 'h'. I would like to do

```
a@A$ scp b@B:h
```

then press 'tab', and see the list of files in B that start with 'h', just like in the example above. Is this possible?

**Edit**:

Here is how I tried to do this by following pLumo's suggested answer:

```
    $ ssh b@B
    Last login: xxx
    b@B:~$ ls
    my_file.dat
    b@B:~$ exit
    logout
    Shared connection to B closed.
    $ cat ~/.ssh/config
      Host B

          Hostname B.xxxx.xx

          User b


          ControlMaster auto    
           ControlPath ~/.ssh/control:%h:%p:%r

    $ scp b@B:my_file.dat .
    my_file.dat                                                                                                                                   100%    4     0.0KB/s   00:00  
    $ssh -fN b@B  
    $ scp b@B:my_ 

where at the end of the last line I pressed TAB, but nothing happens.
```

Comment: Yes, this is possible. zsh for example has support for scp autocompletion

Answer (score 1):

Tab completion works well for `scp` if you have one of these:

---

**First option:**

Reuse connections, add this to your `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host B
    User b
    ControlMaster auto
    ControlPath ~/.ssh/control:%h:%p:%r
```

For tab completion to work, you need to have a connection already open. You can start one in the background if you don't have one already open:

```
ssh -fN B
```

This even works via `JumpHost`.

---

**Second option**:

Use Public/Pricate Keys, `scp` will automatically use these. Downside is, `scp` will need to login each time which might be a bit slower than reusing already established connections.

Comment: I have tried the first option, and it does not work. If I understand correctly, I must add to ~/.ssh/config 'Host A...' where A is the host from which I am trying to connect, not the one to which I am trying to connect, right? In this case A would be my local computer, so I suspect that I should write 'Host local'.

Comment: Also, it is not clear how to practically implement the second option.

Comment: Sorry, I got A/B wrong. You have that config on local host (A) for the foreign host (B).

Comment: Thank you. This still does not work: I added the lines that you suggested to ~/.ssh/config, made `$ssh -fN B`, then `$scp b@B:file` and pressed TAB, but no autocompletion.

Comment: and `file...` exists in B's users home?

Comment: Yes, see my revised answer.